# Torque on shaft

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, education, vectors

Consider a generator which supply power using a shaft to a turbine. The 
torque applied on shaft by generator is $T$. As the shaft has constant angular velocity the turbine should also be applying same torque $T$. My question is how can turbine apply this torque. If it is capable of giving equal opposite torque how can it accelerate (actually I wonder how it would have accelerated from rest if it's capable of giving equal opposite reaction)

Comment: Consider using math formatting with `$...$` for better readability. See [help on LaTeX](http://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex)

Comment: The answer is that the torque is applied on different objects. It is the same as when you push a block. You push and it moves forward, while it pushes you back and slows you down.

Answer (score 0):

This is no different than the linear motion case. The generator moves because torque is applied **to it**. In response it applies torque **to the shaft turning it**. The net torque on the system is zero but individual components feel (opposite) net torques.

This is absolutely fundamental to understanding any Newtonian mechanics.